# Trying to create 2 columns out of 1 column of data using offset and indirect

Tags: excel, formula, offset, excel-indirect

Need to take 1 column of data and create 2 columns for maximizing the amount of data on each sheet.

Ive been working with offset and indirect formulas but not getting the expected results. Below are just a few examples of what ive tried and worked with and tried changing to get what i think i should be getting.

```
=IF(OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COLUMN()-1)*10+ROW()-1,0)="","",OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,(COLUMN()-1)*310+ROW()-1,0))

=OFFSET($A$1,ROW()*1-2+COLUMN(),0)&""

=INDIRECT("a"&ROW()*1-(2-COLUMN()))
```

So we have a need to create a excel template as dynamic as possible with as little printed pages as we can. Because the number of rows is unknown, we want to build the template in a fashion that allows for as little or as much data as we receive and need printed. So we have a need to fit 2 column sets per page, each set containing 10 rows each so we can have a total of 20 sets per page.

After finding offset and indirect, i started to work with that and see if i can create a formulas that would give me what we need..

What we are trying to see by using these formulas(if they are the correct ones to use) is the following:

Say we have 25 rows in our datasheet. We would like to see the following on our template.

```
Page 1

1     11

2     12

3     13

4     14

5     15

6     16

7     17

8     18

9     19

10    20


Page 2

21

22

23

24

25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use INDIRECT and OFFSET if possible (And I have only found rare times they are needed) as they are volatile functions.  Index is the best option:

Page1 put this in the first cell, copy over one and down ten:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,Row(1:1)+((column(A:A)-1)*10))
```

In each sequential sheet add a factor of 20:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,Row(1:1)+((column(A:A)-1)*10)+(20*1))
```

Change the `*1` to `*2` for the third and so on.

Comment: Can this method be changed to be dynamic? Meaning i know we will only want a max of 20 per page, it can be less if we dont have enough to fill a page, but if we say 135 rows, will we have to do the counting ourselves and tweek the formula for every 20?

Comment: Yes, it would need to be manual as a formula cannot tell on which number sheet it is being placed.  For that you would need vba.

Comment: So i love your example and in its simple form, it works great.. How can i modify the formula to incorporate my current formulas in my spreadsheet?    Here is what i have in my A1 cell         =UPPER(Data!O2)    would i place that into the formula =INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,ROW(1:1)+((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*10)) in place of the "Sheet1!$A:$A"

Comment: No, you would wrap the whole formula in UPPER(...)

Comment: So i modified the formula for column 1 in my sheet to this =INDEX(Data!$A2,ROW($1:$1)+((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*10)) and this works for the first set of 10, but when i try to copy the formula in column 2 with the continuation formula it gives a #REF error

Comment: This is my 2nd column formula that gets the error        =UPPER(INDEX(Data!$A2,ROW($1:$1)+((COLUMN(B:B)-1)*10)))

Comment: you modified the formula incorrectly: `UPPER(Data!$A:$A,ROW(1:1)+((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*10)) ` copy over and down.

Comment: So just to make sure, im building a new template with this formula and see if i can use it as i think it will work.. So i just need to use the same formula in each column i want to wrap around ONLY changing the cell that contains the data i want to display in that new place on the template.

Comment: I think at this point the best thing to do is ask a new question so you can show what you have and what you want and what you tried,  I am getting confused with just comments.

Comment: Ill open another question soon, i was able to start setting up the template with your last example and seems to be working, just need to format things.. if there was a way to post a picture of how i need it and how its setup i would, thank you Scott..